# Kth largest number in an array using "Sort K number of elements based array" algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, pointers

I am trying to implement the following algorithm to find the kth largest number of inputs given in a text file. The first number determines k variable, the next number determines total number of elements (N), and the rest is the number list. 
The Algorithm description is:

- Store only the first k numbers in an array
- Sort the array in decreasing order, e.g., using insertion sort
- Read the rest of the numbers one by one:
- Ignore if it is smaller than the number at kth position in the array
- Otherwise; insert it in its correct position in the array and shift the
  remaining numbers (the number at the kth position will be thrown
  out of the array)
- Return the number at index k-1 in the array.

```
AlgorithmSortK::AlgorithmSortK(int k) : SelectionAlgorithm(k)
{
    this->k = k;

}



int AlgorithmSortK::select()
{

    int N = 0;
    int x=0;
    int *pNums = 0;
    cin>>N;
    cout<<"N:"<<N<<endl;
    pNums = new int[N];
     int key, j;
    for (int i=0; i<k; i++)
    {
        cin>>x;
        pNums[i] = x;
        cout<<pNums[i]<<endl;



        for (i = 1; i <k; i++)
        {
            key = pNums[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && pNums[j] <key)
            {
                pNums[j + 1] = pNums[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            pNums[j + 1] = key;
        }

        for ( i=k; i<N; i++)
        {
            cin>>x;

            if(x>pNums[k-1])
            {

                for (int shifter=0; shifter<k; shifter++)
                {
                    pNums[shifter]=x;

                    pNums[shifter] =  pNums[shifter+1];

                }
                for (int r = 1; r <k; r++)
                {

                    key = pNums[r];
                    j = r - 1;
                    while (j >= 0 && pNums[j] <key)
                    {
                        pNums[j + 1] = pNums[j];
                        j = j - 1;
                    }
                    pNums[j + 1] = key;

                }
            }
        }
        cout<<"pNums[k-1]:"<<pNums[k-1]<<endl;
    }
```

This is my code, it compiles correctly but I got a different and incorrect result for pNums[k-1]. I think I am doing the shifting and removing the element at k-1 index operations incorrectly. N is the total number of elements, and I am using insertion sorting for the k-limited array.

Comment: "`pNums = new int[N]`". Idea is to store only `K` elements, so you can already reduce the size here.

Comment: It seems your first loop should not include the other loops.

Comment: Seems you have problems with {} parens for the first for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
int AlgorithmSortK::select()
{
    int N, x;

    cin >> N;    // number of the input elements
    cout << "N:" << N << endl;

    std::vector<int> nums;
    nums.resize( k, std::numeric_limits<int>::min() );    // assume 'k' is defined elsewhere

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;  // get the next element

        // shift it down while it's larger than existing numbers
        for( int j=0; j<k; j++) {
            if( x > nums[j] ) {
                std::swap( x, nums[j] );
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"nums[k-1]:" << nums[k-1]<<endl;
}
```

The complexity is `O(N*k)`, could make it faster, but I'd rather have it simpler.

Comment: @Jarod42 `nums.resize( k );` -> `nums.resize( k, NEGATIVE_NUMBER );`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works fine! But since I am at the basics of C++, I have tried to use dynamic allocation explicitly. Did not try to use Vector and Limits libraries before. I suppose that I need to free the vector from the memory after its operation is done.

Comment: @utdlegend please, never use dynamic allocation. `std::vector` will manage the menory itself, and you don't have to worry about anything. with dynamic memory allocation you'll shoot yourself in the foot every once in a while. using `numeric limits` is a bit silly, but Jarod42 insisted on that, if you write a simple sample and not going to use a lot of negative numbers, you may skip that part, leaving just `nums.resize( k )`.